# gitlab: access token is not able to push to container registry

Tags: gitlab

I've just created an personal token with `read_registry` and `write_registry` permissions.

I'm getting this message:

```
$ docker login registry.gitlab.com -u xxxx -p xxxx
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/jeusdi/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
```

And then,

```
$ docker image push registry.gitlab.com/<group>/<project>
The push refers to repository [registry.gitlab.com/<group>/<project>]
1dc94a70dbaa: Preparing 
704d744650ba: Preparing 
195ce6778985: Preparing 
5f70bf18a086: Preparing 
ef005e9057c2: Preparing 
c4537747ad1e: Waiting 
7a2d1e495085: Waiting 
c8916d4670b0: Waiting 
fcc507beb4cc: Waiting 
720a7daa6797: Waiting 
e3b397f100a1: Waiting 
7fbc97c38fad: Waiting 
a37a586cf5a0: Waiting 
ec0381c8f321: Waiting 
4f3c20a6d24d: Waiting 
a53ff049d96e: Waiting 
cdad8d247d1d: Waiting 
af02a81787a4: Waiting 
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try adding an image name to the path? Like `registry.gitlab.com/<group>/<project>/<image>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an image contained *within* `/group/project/*` not just `/group/project`

For [example](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/#build-and-push-images-by-using-docker-commands-1):

```
docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/group/project/image .
docker push registry.gitlab.com/group/project/image
```

Comment: I tried it. It's strange since documentation you referenced is so clear. Take a look on this [asciinema](https://asciinema.org/a/8qKr32QPk9u5Agf18NBNvAcZY).

Comment: @Jordi I would double check your authentication configuration. Are you absolutely sure you gave both read AND write permissions to your token (this is needed). Also double check your docker client version is up to date. If you still have issues, could you edit your question to include the output of `docker info` ?

Comment: It might also be noteworthy that your image name can have one slash in it, but I got an error when it had two.  `../mygroup/myproj/path/to/image:tag` failed but `../mygroup/myproj/path/image:tag` worked.